# Does the for-loop only run one time in python class?

Tags: python-3.5, pyqt5

I want to show ten lines of 'test' label in one window, so I use the for-loop,  but it only shows one line.
 I guess the for-loop in my code is put the wrong place, but I don't know how to make it correct.

Here is the main code:

```
class Home(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Home, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(300,100,400,300)
        self.scrollLayout = QFormLayout()

        self.scrollWidget = QWidget()
        self.scrollWidget.setLayout(self.scrollLayout)

        self.scrollArea = QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollWidget)

        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.Lbl = QLabel('test')
        for i in range(20):### here, it only loops 1 time
            self.scrollLayout.addRow(self.Lbl)

        self.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

this

```
1        self.Lbl = QLabel('test')
2        for i in range(20):### here, it only loops 1 time
3            self.scrollLayout.addRow(self.Lbl)
```

you need to put line 1 actually in the for-loop(line 2...line 3)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating only one label known inside your class. Any Widget type (QLabel), can be added only once to any "container". So you are adding the same label 20 times, when you add a label somewhere else or in the same place you remove the old one and add it to the new place, one label cannot be at two places at the same time.

---

Here is the thing, you have to create one new label each loop so you would have something like that:

```
for i in range(20):
    lbl = QLabel("teste"+str(i)) # here you are creating one new label to each loop
    self.scrollLayout.addRow(lbl)
```

But remember, in this way now you do not have an instance saved in a variable of each label, to access each one you will have to iterate in your scrollLayout and take one by one to modify them. 
Another thing you can do is to have a list that you append each of your labels and can easily access them later on.